# How to find all occurrences in my source code where std::string is passed to methods as a copy rather than a constant reference?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stdstring

I'm optimizing a large project, and want to replace passing arguments of type 'std::string' to methods with 'const std::string&' wherever possible. How can I find all occurrences where strings are passed to methods as a copy in my source code tree? I'm using Visual Studio 2012, but can also do this in any convenient IDE/OS.

So far I tried to find all occurrences of 'string ', but got over 11k lines of occurrences to review, including those where strings are class fields, and passed as constant references (which is not to be replaced)

Comment: Passing a `std::string` by value is correct if it then gets moved. Arguably you should ban all occurances of `const std::string &` passing and either use `std::string` or `std::string_view`.

Comment: A regex seems reasonable. If you need to cover complicated cases like typedefed `std::string`s then consider clang-query.

Comment: When optimizing, measure first (and second, and again once you're done). Without measurements how do you know that what you are doing is going to have a positive effect at all? Your effort would probably be better invested elsewhere.

Comment: But if I had to actually do this, I would take an editor to `bits/basic_string.h` and mark the copy constructor as `[[deprecated]]`, which generates a warning when it is used.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use Cppcheck and parse output.

main.cpp:

```
void bar(string str) {
    cout << str; 
}
```

terminal:

```
cppcheck --enable=performance test.cpp
```

output:

```
Checking main.cpp ...
[main.cpp:5]: (performance) Function parameter 'str' should be passed by const reference.
```

2) Also clang tidy can act in the same way.
For example, 
[CLion show warning on useless string copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WR4z.png)

You can use Clang analize manualy and parse output.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using a static code analyzer (you can google, there are a lot of them). They usually suggest such optimizations.

Another option is using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). It can parse the code and list all the functions in a standard format easy to search. To do this set the maximal output options in the configuration file (may be it will work even with default options, but just in case)

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
```

and enable XML output

```
GENERATE_XML           = YES
```

Then run `doxygen` over your project and search for all the `string` arguments without a subsequent `&` or `*` in the output XMLs. E.g. using `grep`:

```
 grep -B 1 -E '<argsstring>.*string [^&*].*</argsstring>' *.xml > result.txt
```

This should get something like

```
classMyClass.xml-        <definition>void MyClass::myMethod</definition>
classMyClass.xml:        <argsstring>(std::string x)</argsstring>
```

Doxygen has many other cool code analysis features that can be useful in refactoring: it can make include diagrams, class diagrams, call graphs etc.